# How can I view all of my Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook

I make posts on my wall every day. Though when I view my own timeline, some of my posts are not displayed. I use [Qsearch](https://apps.facebook.com/fbqsearch/?fb_source=search&ref=br_tf) application (in Chinese) and it can list all of my posts.

I don't want to use an external application like QSearch like that since they can read my data.

How can I read all of my post using solely Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click your name to see your profile, click the "Activity Log", then click "Your Posts" in the left-hand menu. This will show you everything you've ever posted in reverse chronological order. (It loads as necessary, however, so it may take some time to get to the content you're looking for.)

[image: "Activity Log" link]
[image: Activity Log menu]

Alternatively, you can export all of your Facebook data. Go to "Settings" and then click "Download a copy of your Facebook data". ([help](https://www.facebook.com/help/405183566203254)) Unfortunately, you can't limit this archive to just posts. You'd need to work with it yourself to get just the data you want.